# How do i use the jQuery.parseJSON properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have set of values coming from server side  where iam trying to generate 
  JSON and use it in my code

here is the statement now the problem is it is working perfectly
  if the value is fine with out single quotes and double quotes.

```
var stds = jQuery.parseJSON('<?php echo json_encode($this->emps); ?>');

  CASE 1:
  ABC:"E" DTSM  
  VCD:"E" DMST  

CASE 2:
  *****
  ABC:E DTSM  
  VCD:E DMST
```

How can i still generate the JSON  with case 1. iam getting   JS error "exception thrown  and not caught". This is due to malformed JSON string

Comment: Please show us how the php statement renders.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because JSON is already a valid fragment of JavaScript, you could simply write

```
var stds = <?php echo json_encode( $this->emps ); ?>;
```

Comment: This works for php >= 5.2.  Hopefully not many are using lesser versions.

Answer (score 1):

use `<?php echo json_encode($str); ?>`